# Why computer may have trouble with the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi } \sin (100x)dx$? (Numerical Integration)

Tags: numerical-methods, programming

I encountered this question in the book "Computational Physics: Problem Solving with Computers".
But I can't figure out why computer may have trouble with the numerical integration of $\int_{0}^{2\pi } \sin (100x)dx$?? 
Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maxima gives an answer of $0$ without any apparent struggle.

Comment: It varies between $1$ and $-1$ rapidly. Heuristically: more variation, harder to numerically integrate.

Comment: @copper.hat That's symbolic integration or numeric? A numeric integrator of the olden days could have had some trouble, today we'd need a higher frequency to get numeric integration into trouble methinks.

Comment: This should't be too hard to solve, since an anti-derivative of $\sin{100x}$ is given by $-\frac{1}{100} \cdot \cos{100x}$. Hence you're actually able to give the precise solution, and do not need to compute the integral numerically.

Comment: Perhaps the author is making a general comment about accumulated errors in numerical computations? The integral above is straightforward by numerical standards...

Comment: @FBiersack Probably, the task was to calculate the integral numerically.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Symbolic; I'm trying to figure out what the author might have meant.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, seems as if....well, that could probably cause some trouble, since the frequency of the sine function is quite high....

Comment: @copper.hat My money is on "arctic term hit the nail on the head". A rapidly oscillating function is bad for numeric integration, since you need a small step to get decent accuracy.

Comment: Yes I'm using numerical integration to solve the problem.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Perhaps, but I'm still a little puzzled. Every modern communication device in the world has been designed & tested using numerical simulations in which the range of Hz-GHz frequencies appear. Stiff perhaps, but not particularly troublesome.

Comment: @copper.hat If you use a program like PARI/GP, the algorithms for the commands are already optimized. But if you program the numerical integration yourself withoue some care, you can get a bad result.

Comment: OP: What exactly do you mean by the computer having trouble with the computation?

Comment: @copper.hat I can't find when the book was first released, but it's not many years since computers were capable of dealing with high frequencies well. Something like 20 years ago, that wasn't something you'd want to let your PC tackle lightly.

Comment: Table calculators often give a result different from $0$, if you enter $\sin(\pi)$. Some users might wonder, why the result is not exactly $0$. Maybe a bit off-topic, but the lesson is that you should not blindly trust the result of a computer.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I'm curious if the OP is encountering an issue, or if this a statement in the book...

Comment: @Peter: Roman 6:23 The wages of $\sin$ is numerical death...

Comment: @Peter: Sorry, it is a joke on a verse from the Bible.

Comment: I'm using Trapezoid Rule, Simpson Rule and Gaussian Quadrature. The result I got by using the three methods is approximately 0.58 . But the exact integral should be 0, right?

Comment: @Elina right. How many points did you use ?

Comment: @Peter I used 350 points.

Comment: @Elina The second derivate is immense. $350$ points may still be not enough. Try again with more points, lets say, $700$ points and tell us the result.

Comment: @Elina: The function has about 200 zero crossings, you might want to consider sampling at a higher rate, for example, take at least 400 points...

Comment: @Elina Are you allowed to substitute $t=100x$ BEFORE calculating the integral numerically ?

Comment: @Moo: That result is spurious because all the samples fall more or less on a zero of the integrand. You would need at least one point in between each pair of zeros to even slightly approximate the result.

Comment: @Elina: Try integrating the function $x \mapsto 1$ as a test of your code.